# Dot product and work

Tags: vectors, inner-products

If I pull something horizontally $\sqrt{3}$ meters by a force of 20 newtons at an angle of $30$ degrees above the horizontal, then how much work is done?

I know how to do it with components but I want to try dot product and I can't seem to get it.

Shouldn't the two vectors be $<10\sqrt{3},10>$ and $<\sqrt{3},0>$

Comment: Yeah it looks correct. Now the dot product is
$$
10\sqrt{3} \cdot \sqrt{3} + 10 \cdot 0 
$$

Comment: Yeah, I got it now... I was doing it both ways and wondering why I couldn't get it... and then realized it was a simplification error in how I did my component version